# How can a modern-day nomadic culture preserve its lifestyle?

Tags: culture, religion, modern

In modern times, how can this ancient clan, bound by religious duty to visit 12 holy sites across Asia each year, and once serving as messengers between kingdoms but no longer doing so, confront the challenges of earning a living in 2024, given travel restrictions and encroachment on their ancestral lands? They continue the nomadic lifestyle of their ancestors, traveling daily on horseback along the same route, and seeking to protect their cultural heritage to avoid extinction.

Comment: What's the problem? I believe that some Mongols still do their nomad thing. Ditto for people of the Arctic. Both earn their living by selling meat and byproducts, which are still valuable in 2024.

Comment: "12 holy sites across Asia" - where are they, exactly?  What have they been doing for the last 100-150 years (at least) since telegraphs and railroads became ubiquitous?  (Writing a fictitious history of the clan that meshes with real-world history for the last century-plus is outside the scope of this site, you need to let us know how things got to this point and what has changed now to trigger the question.)

Comment: In modern countries, these nomads get permission to cross the borders without trouble. They have trouble only with oppressive countries, wars, or where the country has economic trouble.

Comment: Have you researched the Travellers / Gypsies / Roma?

Comment: yes I did my research these people are different from Roma coz they have to visit their holy sites when stars align so they don't have free time like the gypsy who are just travellers and their migration patterns do not repeat

Comment: VTC: Violates Book Rule. This Q is way too broad. It's actually a Q asked by every small town in the U.S. that's trying to preserve their culture/heritage while growing into mid-size and large cities - and there are whole books on the subject. Have you studied (e.g.) the changing culture of the semi-nomadic Mongols? Have you searched Google for "preserving nomadic lifestyle today"? This Q can be equally answered with "use religious taboos" and "everyone else goes green." That's too broad.

Answer (score 2):

### Same as they always did and always will do

They would probably do the same things they always did. Live for 95% self-contained lives. Having their herd with them and scavenging for the rest. For the few things they can't produce themselves (e.g. metal wares), they would trade in the villages they pass through each year offering a surplus of the things they do produce. Mainly meat and other animal-based products as well as some services, like hair cutting. The villages would be used to it and always anticipate the next arrival of the nomads, hoping for new nice meat, enjoying good stories and their unique music, and fearing for the virginity of their daughters. Since it happens every year, most people in the villages grew up with it.

However, their travels would always have new hardships. During conflicts, they will have difficulty passing certain borders but maybe they can contact some high-ranking officers they already knew when they were mere border patrol soldiers to pull some strings, after all, they are a well-known sight along these borders as they pass them year by year.

Also, highways and villages turning to cities would force them to alter their routes sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

**Do they need to *earn* a living, or do they already have one?**

Totally self-contained lifestyles like this are interesting in that the concept of “earning a living” goes out the window. If you need sleep, you find a place to rest; if you need food, you hunt for some. Dependence on a state is not necessary, as is evidenced by the many existing stateless nations; these people just execute the “stateless nation” thing on a broader scale.

As far as avoiding bureaucracy when crossing borders? Simple: *get passports*. After such a long time, surely some members of this group will have at least partially integrated with the rest of society (after all, who doesn’t like being tracked and monitored at all times by the corporate supergiants that control TikTok?). These people would ensure that the group secures travel materials like passports, hunting permissions in the land they cross through, and the like. These partially-integrated members might not even reside with the rest of the group: maybe they live in smaller towns near where the group travels each year, and every year there’s a little “reunion” between the TikTok user and their nomadic family.

If these people are sufficiently distributed across the route the group crosses, I see no major issues. Just watch for cars when you cross the highway!